# ключи объекта как параметры функции

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

Как правильно вставить keys объекта в параметры функции?
Т.е. чтобы было "function createElemFunc(varName, parentVarName, tag, tagClass...)"

```
var createElemObj = {
    varName:         'wrapper', 
    parentVarName:   'parentWrapper', 
    tag:             'div', 
    tagClass:        'wrapper', 
    parentTag:       'body', 
    tagAttribute:    'style', 
    attributeValues: 'width: 100%; min-width: 800px;', 
    innerStuff:      '', 
    positionNum:     '0'
};

function createElemFunc(createElemObj){
    varName = document.createElement(tag);
    varName.classList.add(tagClass);
    parentVarName = document.querySelector(parentTag);
    parentVarName.insertBefore(varName, parentVarName.children[positionNum]);
    varName.innerHTML = innerStuff;
    varName.setAttribute(tagAttribute, attributeValues);    
};
createElemFunc();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createElemFunc(createParams) {
  var newElement = document.createElement(createParams.tag);
  newElement.classList.add(createParams.tagClass);
  var parentElement = document.querySelector(createParams.parentTag);
  parentElement.insertBefore(
    newElement, parentElement.children[createParams.positionNum]);
  newElement.innerHTML = createParams.innerStuff;
  newElement.setAttribute(createParams.tagAttribute, createParams.attributeValues);    
};

var createElemObj = {
  varName:         'wrapper', 
  parentVarName:   'parentWrapper', 
  tag:             'div', 
  tagClass:        'wrapper', 
  parentTag:       'body', 
  tagAttribute:    'style', 
  attributeValues: 'width: 100%; min-width: 800px;', 
  innerStuff:      '', 
  positionNum:     0
};

createElemFunc(createElemObj);
```